# Изменение размеров img в зависимости от размера родителя

Tags: javascript, html, css

Стоит задача создания карты-схемы территории. Карта представляет собой png-файл, на котором нарисованы здания. Каждое здание имеет отдельную картинку (тоже самое здание, которое подсвечено и обладает булавкой с номером здания). Нужно , чтобы при наведении на здание появлялась данная картинка. Думаю реализовать так: разместить поверх карты-картинки над каждым зданием div-блоки, при наведении на div-блок показывать картинку здания. Проблема в том, что сами блоки и картинки здания нужно "скейлить" в зависимости от размера окна. Сейчас размещаю так:

```
    <div class="SchemeTerritoryImage">
        <img src="map2.png" class="img-fluid" alt="">
        <a href="#" id="sklad17" style="position: absolute; left: 16%; top: 64%;"><img src="17.png" class="img-fluid"></a> 
    </div>
```

В css-файле:

```
    .SchemeTerritoryImage {  
    margin: 40px auto; /* верхний и нижний отступы и горизонтальное выравнивание */
    position: absolute;
    }
```

Размещение объектов вроде понял, как сделать. А как изменять размер div-блоков и img, не знаю, возможно через js-скрипт. Возможно, Вы подскажите иную реализацию?

Comment: Приложите ваш код в виде рабочего сниппета, который можно запустить и посмотреть.

Comment: а какая зависимость от родителя? .SchemeTerritoryImage - от него надо скейлить? или от размера окна все таки?

Comment: Для такого все же более уместно будет использовать canvas или svg.

Comment: @Skywave скорее от родителя, а он сам скейлится от размера окна. С картинками проблему решил, теперь картинки со зданием равны по размеру с картинкой-схемой, просто содержат прозрачный фон и само здание в правильном расположении. Осталось решить проблему с div-блоками и их изменением размера.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko согласен полностью с Вами. SVG - идеальное решение, но картинка в png и перерисовывать отказываются.

Comment: Не проще ли использовать  <map>?: http://htmlbook.ru/html/map, Free on-line generator областей https://www.image-map.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я в качестве ознакомления сделал этот пример 
Выделил при hover два элемента(ноутбук и лист бумаги) и повесил события 
Ну в общем смотрите пример

> Может быть img сюда не прогрузится : https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/VobZqa

```css
img{
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.items{
  width: 640px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  position: relative;
}

.item-svg{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
}

#laptop,#paper{
  fill: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#paper:hover,
#laptop:hover{
  fill: rgba(255,0,0,0.4);
}

#t1{
  fill: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  
}

.hover{
  transform: translate(100px, 0);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.34s;
}

#border{
  fill: none;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

.els:hover .hover{
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item-img">
    <img src="https://img1.goodfon.ru/original/3399x2163/b/15/biblioteka-polki-knigi.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="item-svg">
    <svg width="640" height="405" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <g class="els">
        <title>Laptop</title>
        <g class="hover">
        <text x="150" y="150" id="t1">Это такой крутой Ноутбук</text>
        <rect id="border" x="125" y="125" width="200" height="40" rx="10"></rect>
        </g>
        <path d="M70,182 220,183 230,270 260,283 77,297 73,280z" id="laptop">
       
      </g>
        <g>
          <title>List</title>
          <path d="M237,315 370,315 400,370 205,372z" id="paper"/>
        </g>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А что на счет измнения размера картинки? Кажется, в вопросе был упор именно на это. *А как изменять размер div-блоков и img*

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko я не понял не много - автор согласился с такой реализацией